What is the time signature in Metallica's "Nothing Else Matters"
The song is very popular and has been notated countless times, in all possible ways. What note values and time signature should be used to notate the music?
The main six note guitar pattern:

seems to represent the rhythm followed through the whole song. There is a single exception in at the beginning of the guitar intro, where 3 extra notes are added once – I think this can be disregarded. Maybe the time signature changes for a single measure there.
Does the main motif use eighth-notes or quarter-notes?

To me, eighth-notes would suggest a faster tempo. Moreover, the vocal melody uses twice shorter durations. I'm used to quarter-notes and eighth-notes being the typical building blocks of the vocal melodies (rather than eighth-notes and sixteenth-notes) – but maybe that's wrong way to think of it?
Is the main motif a single measure, or two measures?

Through the whole song, there are strong accents on the first and the fourth note of the pattern, making me want to split it in two measures. However, the two halves are strongly tied to each other. In particular the drums play the kick with the first guitar note and a snare with the fourth, which in turn suggests the motif is a single measure.

In the internet, one can already find many different answers to this question. Therefore, I'm looking for  answers supported with good quality reference examples of similar music or notation guidelines.
If you believe the answer is "it doesn't matter", I'm also requesting to provide evidence how similar music was notated in different ways.
I'm also aware that Metallica released an official transcription of the songs from Black Album, and it seemed well-prepared to me. However, I think it's more interesting to compare the song with examples of other similar music.

Does this answer your question? Confusion with identifying the bottom number of the time signature of a song by ear

@AndyBonner it kind of does. Making "it doesn't matter" the answer I'm looking for.

I have a strong but not so popular opinion that in rock, the time signature is explicit in the drum part. For example, the vast majority of the time, the hi hat indicates eighth notes. Perhaps that will help you feel the pulse of “Nothing Else Matters”.

I picked that one as a proposed duplicate, but there are a lot of others on the topic; try searching “time signature”

It might help to know that stylistically this classifies as rock ballad, which is usually 6/8 with a slower tempo. And about the tempo: That is exactly why we do have tempo markings. Compare 2nd movement of B’s 3rd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTbesxdLwo8&t=808s with the 3rd movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTbesxdLwo8&t=1797s First has small note values, but slow tempo. Second has large note values, but fast tempo.

@ToddWilcox yes, this sounds right to me. If you could expand it a bit, it would make a useful answer, I believe.

@Lazy well, I know how the tempo markings work. In both Beethoven examples the time signature has 4 at the bottom, which suggests a quarter note is supposed to be the pulse. In Nothing Else Matters it's a bit less obvious to me, for some reason.

It's a lot like my answer to the linked question: there's no "inherent" or objective reason to pick one or the other, but some reasons of cultural convention. Speed it up just slightly and it would become doo-wop, and I doubt many would choose a quarter note beat ("one-and-a-TWO-and-a"). As it is, the individual notes are about 150 bpm, which is not unusually fast for a quarter (for a 3/4 waltz, it isn't even as brisk as Viennese convention), but would mean a dotted quarter of ca 45bpm, a very slow feel. Like my answer there: the original artist could decide what they think of it, but any..

... any later transcriber must either make their best guess at the original intent, or impose their own editorial intent. And no matter what, it makes very little (if any) impact on the actual sound, and more impact simply on how we think and how it looks on the page.

I voted to re-open. This question is about interpretation, not identification and I believe it should be allowed regardless of whatever the fine print is for what is on and off topic.

I'm a bit surprised about the close reason. I think the question is indeed about transcribing. However the justification to close it is that it is not "useful to future readers". Do a quick internet search to find that the question about the time signature of this particular song is often asked, and I believe a well written answer would benefit the future readers. I leave it up to the community what to do with the question, but even closing as a duplicate pointed by Andy would make more sense to me.

@JohnBelzaguy I agree; this is not a request for transcription so much as a question about meter that uses a song as an example. (And the discussion history in the meta section suggests that we want to support transcription questions that are not "gimme the notes" but rather "how does one approach this issue.") But there are definitely several other questions here already about the dilemma of picking a note value for the pulse, and distinguishing between measure lengths and phrase lengths. ...

...  (See some of the discussions about Norwegian Wood.) To user1079505, be aware that the "close reason" given is simply the "majority" one, not that everyone picked that reason, and that the text given is by necessity a bit "one size fits all."

Man, this makes me want to expand my answer to my proposed duplicate. Because there is more to it than "Do whatever the hell you want." If we hear a series of notes, once they get above a certain speed we're inclined to view them not as individual pulses but as subdivisions of a slower pulse, and similarly if they get slow enough we perceive them as notes containing multiple pulses. This is clearest when we decide how to conduct them, so I suspect it stems from some kind of kinesthetic/proprioceptive sense.

I prefer 6/8, the most used metric for binary compound time. The bottom number could be 2,4,8,16 et cetera, and you still could read this perfectly. But 6/8 is most habitual.

Through the whole song, there are strong accents on the first and the fourth note of the pattern, making me want to split it in two measures.

This is a binary feeling. If you listen carefully, note 4 is weaker than note 1, but stronger than all others. But, my friend, metric (at least in music) is an idea - and a very malleable one. You could write this in 3/4 or even 3/8 with an accent on beat 1 every two measures without "ruining" the song. But, again, I prefer write this in 6/8 - it's clearer, easier to read and communicate the right metric feeling for the player.
Now, a little rant about official transcriptions: they suck! I researched Dream Theater for my master's degree, and basically needed to re-transcribe all the parts from the chosen songs (6 songs from SFAM) due to controversies and discrepancies on official transcriptions for guitar, bass and keys. It was an almost endless nightmare.

6/8 or maybe 12/8 is also suggested by the drum part. Often rock drums have hats on 1/8 notes, kick on downbeats and snare on weaker beats. Lars Ulrich’s drum patterns in this song are commonly used for 6/8 and 12/8 meters.
